# How could I extract all digits and strings from the first list into other list?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the first list call OGList that have a list of strings, after that I want to extract all digits and strings from the OGList into a list of string and a list of digits.

My Input:

```
OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']

numlist = []
strlist = []
otherlist = []

for i in OGList:
    for x in i:
        if x.isalpha():
            strlist.append(x)
        elif x.isdigit():
            numlist.append(x) 
        else:
            otherlist.append(x)

print(numlist)
print(strlist)
```

My Output:

```
['1', '0', '3', '2', '0', '2', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0']
['A', 'B', 'M', 'W', 'i', 'N', 'i', 's', 's', 'a', 'n', 'N', 'S', 'X', 'B', 'e', 'n', 'z', 'c']
```

But I want it to stick together like my desired output.

My desired output is:

```
['10', '320', '200', '220']
['A', 'BMWi', 'NissanNSX', 'Benzc']
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: I don't think you need to do that!! You can just use regex on the OGList: `[re.findall(r'\d+', s) for s in OGList]`

Comment: In your example, there is exactly one string per list-item, even if those were two separate parts in the original string, like for "Benzc". So, what's the expected output for a string with no digits (or chars, respectively)? An empty string, or no string?

Comment: Do you need `otherlist` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `regex`, here's an alternative approach using the same to separate the three groups:

```
import re
OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']
types = {"chars": "[a-zA-Z]", "nums": "[0-9]", "other": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"}
res = {k: [''.join(re.findall(types[k], s)) for s in OGList] for k in types}
```

Afterwards, `res` is a dict with the different lists in it:

```
{
  'chars': ['A', 'BMWi', 'NissanNSX', 'Benzc'],
  'nums': ['10', '320', '200', '220'],
  'other': ['', '', ' ', ' ']
}
```

Note that there's not `elif` and `else` here, you have to make sure the patterns are mutually exclusive and covering all the cases, which negating `^` the other groups should do nicely.

Comment: tip of the cap for noticing and following the regex tag. that is a very slick dictionary/list comprehension trick.  and for doing it all in basically two lines. bravo sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
    OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']
    
    dig_lst = []
    letter_lst = []
    
 # with tobias_k suggestion of using negation classes the code becomes very simple.
    for i in OGList:
      
       letter_lst.append(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", "", i))
       dig_lst.append(re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', i))
      
    
 print(dig_lst)
 print(letter_lst)
        
 ['10', '320', '200', '220']
 ['A', 'BMWi', 'NissanNSX', 'Benzc']
```

Comment: That use of regex is a bit weird... first, you `re.sub` all spaces, then you `re.split` by digits and join what remains? What about other symbols? Using `re.sub` is actually a good idea, you could probably just do `letter_lst.append(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", "", i))` or something like that.

Comment: @tobias_k, you are correct. thanks for poiting this out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you'll need a temporary str to add to before list insertion for each pass

```py
OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']

numlist = []
strlist = []
otherlist = []

for i in OGList:
    mystr = ''
    myint = ''
    myother = ''
    for x in i:
        if x.isalpha():
            mystr += x
        elif x.isdigit():
            myint += x
        else:
            myother += x
   if mystr:
       strlist.append(mystr)
   if myint:
       numlist.append(myint)
   if myother:
       otherlist.append(myother)

print(numlist)
print(strlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate output string for each input string, not just append each character onto the output lists.

```
OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']

numlist = []
strlist = []
otherlist = []

for i in OGList:
    numstring = strstring = otherstring = ""
    for x in i:
        if x.isalpha():
            strstring += x
        elif x.isdigit():
            numstring += x
        else:
            otherstring += x
    if strstring:
        strlist.append(strstring)
    if numstring:
        numlist.append(numstring)
    if otherstring:
        otherlist.append(otherstring)

print(numlist)
print(strlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a weird [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)-based approach?

```
from itertools import groupby

OGList = ['A10', 'BMW320i', 'Nissan NSX200', 'Benz 220c']


def get_char_class(char):
    if char.isalpha():
        return 'a'
    if char.isdigit():
        return 'n'
    return 'o'


grouped = [groupby(word, key=get_char_class) for word in OGList]
group_dict = [{k: ''.join(g) for k, g in group} for group in grouped]
result = {}
for d in group_dict:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
# or you can go bonkers and cook up this monstrosity instead of proper loops
# [result.setdefault(k, []).append(v) for d in group_dict for k, v in d.items()]
```

```
{'a': ['A', 'i', 'NSX', 'c'], 'n': ['10', '320', '200', '220'], 'o': [' ', ' ']}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend list comprehension abuse.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you mean the last line?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @KellyBundy, fair enough!  Rewritten =)